# jQuery 2 click functions, one not triggering

Tags: jquery, function, click

I'm trying to make a header that can slide down to reveal a contact form and some other content, triggered by a div inside that header.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="button" class="openpanel"></div>
</div>
```

`#header` has a margin-top of -300px

And here's my jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".openpanel").click(function(){

        $("#header").animate({

            "margin-top": "0px"

        })

      $("#button").removeClass("openpanel")
      $("#button").addClass("closepanel")


   });  


    $(".closepanel").click(function(){

        $("#header").animate({

            "margin-top": "-300px"

        }) 

      $("#button").removeClass("closepanel")
      $("#button").addClass("openpanel")


   });  


});
```

---

The problem is that it slides down perfectly, the classes show up properly, but when I click the button a second time the header doesn't slide up again.

Comment: use the live("click",function(){ // your code}) instead of click

Comment: @RegisteredUser `.live(...)` has been deprecated for a while....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `.closepanel` didn't exist when the click handler was bound. In such cases you delegate events using `.on` to the container/document object.

See below,

Change `$(".openpanel").click(function(){` as below,

```
$("#header").on('click', '.openpanel', function(){
```

and

Change `$(".closepanel").click(function(){`

```
$("#header").on('click', '.closepanel', function(){
```

You can achieve what you are doing using a single function,

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    var mTop = 0;
    if ($(this).hasClass('openpanel')) {
        $(this).removeClass('openpanel').addClass('closepanel');
    } else {
        mTop = -300;
        $(this).removeClass('closepanel').addClass('openpanel'); 
    }

    $("#header").animate({ "marginTop": mTop });
});
```

Comment: @Neal Thanks.. was my bad.. trying to juggle between many tabs and missing a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Try coding the handler for the button in one function instead of two separate functions.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button").on('click', function() {
        var margin = '';
        if ($(this).hasClass('openpanel')) {
            $(this).removeClass("openpanel").addClass("closepanel");
            margin = '0px';
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("closepanel").addClass("openpanel");
            margin = '-300px';
        }

        $("#header").animate({
            "margin-top": margin
        })
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something more like this

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="button" class="openpanel"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#button").click(function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    if ($self.hasClass("openpanel")) {
      $("#header").animate({
          "margin-top": "0px"
      })
      $self.removeClass("openpanel")
      $self.addClass("closepanel")
    } else if ($self.hasClass("closepanel")) {
      $("#header").animate({
        "margin-top": "-300px"
      }) 
      $self.removeClass("closepanel")
      $self.addClass("openpanel")
    }     
});
```

Comment: Well I now fixed it even more so you do not have to keep selecting the same thing over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to the on() function:

```
 $(".closepanel").on('click',function(){
```